# Cookie not being set on angular client

Tags: django, angular, cookies

I have a backend app in django python and it is being served on http://localhost:8000.

I have a angular frontend which is being served on http://localhost:4200.

I have disabled CORS on django.
On hitting the login api on http://localhost:8000/auth/login/, I am getting a valid response
along with the Set-Cookie header.
[image]

Here is my angular code to print the cookies:

```
  this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/auth/login/', this.LoginForm, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(response => {
   console.log("response is ", response);
   var cookies = this.cookieService.getAll();//('cookies');
   console.log("cookies is :", cookies);
```

It prints an empty object on console.
How do I make this work? I want to use cookies for authentication.

Answer (score 15):

You are trying to set cross domain cookies,  which will not work straight away. There are a few steps to follow to be able to do that.

1. Set `withCredentials: true` when making the authentication request from angular

   `this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/auth/login/', this.LoginForm, { observe: 'response', withCredentials: true })`
2. Configure your server to return the following CORS headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200`

**Note**

One of the cookies that you are setting is `HttpOnly`. As such, you cannot access it from Javascript (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Security)).

You may not need to access the cookies with JS anyway. If you just want to send the cookies in the next API requests, just pass `withCredentials: true` to `HttpClient` other api calls

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/path/to/get/resource',
  { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(response => {
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Set-Cookies:

In the example in the Question, both client and server are in the same domain, localhost.
On deployment, this may not be the case.
Let us assume the domains as below,

- Client : client1.client.com
- Server: server1.server.com

A http request from the Angular web app in `client1.client.com` to https://server1.server.com/api/v1/getSomething has `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xyz` in the response header.
The cookie will be set on `server1.server.com` and NOT on `client1.client.com`.
You can enter `server1.server.com` in the URL bar and see the cookie being set.

#### withCredentials:

There is no need for the angular app to read the cookie and send it in the following requests. `withCredentials` property of http request can be used for this.
Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Example:

```
public getSomething(): Observable<object> {
    const httpOptions = {
      withCredentials: true
    };
    return this.http.get(`${this.serverUrl}/getSomething`, httpOptions);
  }
```

Refer: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

`withCredentials` will set the cookies from the server's domain in the requests to the server.

As mentioned before `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xyz` in the response from `server1.server.com` will be set in `server1.server.com`. The Angular app in `client1.client.com` need not read it. `withCredentials` will take care of it.

#### cross domain issues:

When the server and client are in different domains, using withCredentials may not work in all browsers, as they are considered as third party cookies.

In my recent testing on May 2020, I found that withCredentials is not working in certain browsers when the client and server are in different domains.

[image]

- In Safari, the issue occurs when "Prevent cross-site tracking" is enabled (by default). The issue is prevented by disabling the same. https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac
- In Android apps, the issue can be avoided by using Chrome Custom Tabs instead of Android WebView. https://github.com/NewtonJoshua/custom-tabs-client , https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

#### Same domain:

Looks like mainstream browsers are moving to block third-party cookies.

- Safari - [Full Third-Party Cookie Blocking and More](https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/)
- Chrome (by 2022) - [Building a more private web: A path towards making third party cookies obsolete](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/building-more-private-web-path-towards.html)

The solution is to have both the client and server in the same domain.

- Client: client1.myapp.com
- Server: server1.myapp.com

And in the `Set-Cookie` response include the root domain too.
Example: "JSESSIONID=xyz; Domain=.myapp.com; Path=/"

This will make sure the cookies are set in all cases.

Comment: Where is this image (table of browser compatibility) from?